# Nutch Fetch failed with protocol status: TEMP_MOVED

Tags: fetch, nutch

We are using Nutch2.3 version, and for some urls we are getting the below mentioned exception while Fetching.

"Fetch failed with protocol status: TEMP_MOVED"

Tried increasing the redirection urls count also, but still getting same error.

Is there any way to fetch and parse this page?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Web server is responding with a redirection instead of the content.

Increase the `http.redirect.max` setting in your `nutch-site.xml` (https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/conf/nutch-default.xml#L341, `0` by default).